# sed: Replace a whole line by number overwriting the original file

Tags: bash, sed, minix

I am writinig a BASH shell script on MINIX where I want to replace entirely a file's specific line by its number with a certain string, and this replacement to be **overwriten to the original file**. Not printed on the `stdout`.

The number of the line and the replacement string are variables of the script with the following names:

```
line (e.g. 8)
repstring (e.g. "134|Wan|Cho|1988-03-20")
```

So I m trying the following code:

```
sed -i "${line}s/.*/${repstring}/" $filename
```

But when I try to execute the script I get the message:

```
sed: unknown option -- i
usage:  sed [-aEnr] script [file ...]
        sed [-aEnr] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

Is it possible to make this file editing in another way?

p.s. I am aware of redirecting the output of the `sed` to a new file and then move the new file to the original, but I don't want to create any other files during the process.

Comment: It seems that your -i parameter is not valid.  Looking at the man pages of sed.  The -i parameter requires an extension and in this case you did not add one.

Comment: I just read about that here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h

But I alreade tried `pkgin update` and `pkgin install sed` but it says that database is up-to-date. So what is the proper way to install that extension manually?

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi the `-i` option does not require an extension in order to perform in-place editing, but adding an extension (eg. `-i.bak`) will create a backup of the original file, now having a `.bak` extension.

Comment: It says right in the error message, his version of `sed` doesn't support the `-i` option. It can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://man.minix3.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Minix+3.3.0&arch=default&format=html), MINIX uses a very minimal version of `sed`. If you want to stick with `sed`, just use redirection, and then move the output file to replace the old one.

```
sed "${line}s/.*/${repstring}/" "$filename" > /tmp/sed.tmp && mv /tmp/sed.tmp "$filename"
```

Or, use Perl:

```
perl -pi -e "if (\$.==$line) {s/.*/$repstring/ && end}" "$filename"
```

The variable `$.` represents the current line number.

Comment: Well this solution works properly. But is it possible to update the `sed` version MINIX uses in order to do this editing without creating any temporary files in the process?

Comment: You could likely download and compile the GNU version, or just use Perl. See my last edit from a few seconds ago.

Comment: Well, I 'll try to download the GNU version in order to make it work and if I still can't fix it that way, I 'll use the redirection method you mentioned.
I cannot use Perl in this project since I still have not been taught about it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @thomas_p: you can't count on sed (even with the `-i` option) to update a file in place. To allow for massive appends or deletes, the software will open a new temp file at a different place on the disk, write the new version, then swap the tmpFile to the origFile . Good luck.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. I finally ended up creating a temprary file to redirect the `sed` output and then swap it with the original one, as MINIX wouldn't support the -i option for `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure what is a character you won't find in `${repstring}`. When a `/` is part of the string, you would like to use some other unique character.

Can you try the old editor `ed`?

```
ed -s "${filename}" << EOF
${linenr}s/.*/${repstring}/g
w
q
EOF
```

When you don't know what would be the unique character, you can use

```
ed -s "${filename}"<< EOF
${linenr}c
${repstring}
.
w
q
EOF
```

But you really should be in control of `repstring`.
Guess what happens with the next repstring:

```
repstring=".
!touch WarnedYou"
```